# libnss-ldap getent passwd - AD replies correctly but output shows local /etc/passwd

Tags: active-directory, ssh, debian, openldap, kerberos

I am trying to configure libnss-ldap to provide AD authentication to my Linux Debian servers. This is working fine if user exists locally, I want to make it work for Domain users.

Here is my /etc/ldap.conf file content:

```
host $AD_IP
base ou=Users,dc=MY,dc=DOMAIN
uri ldap:///$AD_IP
ldap_version 3
binddn $user@MY.DOMAIN
bindpw $password
pam_filter objectclass=user

nss_base_passwd ou=Users,dc=MY,dc=DOMAIN
nss_map_objectclass posixAccount User
nss_map_objectclass shadowAccount User
nss_map_attribute uid sAMAccountName
nss_map_attribute uniqueMember Member
nss_map_attribute homeDirectory unixHomeDirectory
nss_map_objectclass posixGroup Group
pam_login_attribute sAMAccountName
pam_filter objectclass=User
pam_password ad
```

Here is my /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd: compat ldap
group:  compat ldap
shadow: compat ldap
...
```

When I enter the command

```
getent passwd
```

The output is the local /etc/passwd file. But tcpdump shows that the request is correctly made to the AD and the AD returns the whole list of users.
I think data retrieve by the getent command are incorrectly interpreted (nss_map_* incorrectly configured?) and hence getent finally returns local informations (nsswitch first tries ldap then compat).

How to correct this /etc/ldap.conf configuration to make it work?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can I recommend changing how to authenticate users in your AD.

libnss-ldap is a very old library with a lot of memory leaks and it hasn't been updated in years. I don't know why this still available in the distributions and people keep suggesting to use it when we have way better solutions.

I've never used AD, but I'm sure **sssd** can handle that very well.

First link I got from google:
https://blog.dlasley.net/2013/06/configure-linux-for-active-directory-authentication-with-sssd/

I just started using sssd to connect to my OpenLDAP server after I almost killed myself making patches to libnss-ldap and libpam-ldap.

Another library that might work for you if for some reason you're not able to get sssd working. It's **libnss-ldapd**, it's a version based on libnss-ldap and still gets updates, definitely better than libnss-ldap and the latest version (0.9) has pratically all features that libnss-ldap has.

Be aware that even when sssd is properly configured when you use `getent passwd` to get the whole list you don't get the users list from LDAP.

To test you can use `$ id <ldap_user>` or `$ getent passwd <ldap_user>`

`getent` alone only works with libnss-ldap or libnss-ldapd.